# Check item exist in async storage react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using this package  `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` package,

I have made a function to check whether a key exists, if so return true else return false.

Here is my code,

```
export const isAuthuenticated = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@app_user');
    if (data) return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(isAuthuenticated())
```

When I try to console log this `isAuthenticated()` method it gives me an object like this,

```
{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}
```

But I'm expecting to get `true/false` as the returned value.

**Update:**

So I used `.then()` statement since `isAuthenticated()` function is asynchronous, but I receive an error saying **Objects are not valid as a React child** , This is my code,

```
import {isAuthenticated} from './src/middleware/middleware';

const App = async () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isAuthenticated().then(res => res && <AuthNavigator />)};
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I think you need to ```await isAuthuenticated()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async function always returns a promise. So what you need to do to get a boolean result is to either do

```
const res = await isAuthenticated();
console.log(res)
```

Or

```
isAuthenticated().then(res=>console.log(res))
```

If you want to use this in a component, you can simply store the value using an effect as such.

```
    const App = () => {
      const [flag,setFlag] = useState(false);
      useEffect(()=>{
      (
        async()=>{
         const x= await isAuthenticated();
         setFlag(x);
        })()},
      [flag])

      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          {flag && <AuthNavigator />};
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry but this returns me an error saying Objects are not valid as a React child When I try to conditionally render a component

Comment: Can you show the rendering part?

Comment: Let me update my answer for your usecase.

Comment: Can you update your answer upto the component rendering part thanks.

Comment: I have updated it, please check if it suits you!